# Spoofing a message

Tags: mobile, spoofing, sms

Theoretically, if a sender spoofs a number and sends a text, how can the sender get the receiver to reply to the message but having the reply go specifically to a different number?

Comment: They'd have to have control of both numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Technically the reply will go to the spoofed mobile number. You cannot control it unless you are performing a man in the middle attack.